# XPC connection interrupted break at all exceptions app crashes at launch

Tags: ios9, xcode7, xpc

The app crashes at launch the only error is "XPC connection interrupted" no other info, i searched for "keyCommands, keyCommand" tags in the storyboard but no luck there was no such tag, i have no seagues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours of search and trial and error i found the issue, the problem was caused by the storyboard the reason was that i copy paste from other project UITextFields and UILables that had a UIFont that was not added to the current project, after changing the font to System Font the error disappeared and everything worked fine.